# Combining multiple values in method return in C++

Tags: c++, getter-setter

I am trying to see if it is possible to combine multiple get values in the same way you can use a setter in C++. I am using examples from a book which puts each getter on a separate line.

an example I am using for a setter is as follows:

```
void setValues(int, int, string);

void myClass::setValues(int yrs, int lbs, string clr)
{
    this -> age = yrs;
    this -> weight = lbs;
    this -> color = clr;
}
```

Is it possible to do write single line of code for multiple getter values such as these?

```
int getAge(){return age;};
int getWeight(){return weight;}
string getColor(){return color;}
```

Comment: Yes pass by reference instead of returning a value for example `void getValues(int & yrs, int & lbs, string & clr)`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Sure, return a [`std::tuple`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/tuple) by value:

```
std::tuple<int, int, string> getAllTheValues() const
{
    return std::make_tuple(age, weight, color);
}
```

or by reference:

```
std::tuple<int const&, int const&, string const&> getAllTheValues() const
{
    return std::tie(age, weight, color);
}
```

Though you probably don't want to actually write this sort of thing. Just pass the class itself around and use the single-getters you already have.

Comment: I see, thanks. So using the single-getters would still be the best choice in this case

Comment: @Sulaco-Lv223 Unless you have a *strongly compelling* reason to need the multi-getter.

Answer (score 3):

Here's one solution nobody mentioned yet:

```
struct values { int age; int weight; string color; };

values getValues() const
{
    return { this->age, this->weight, this->color };
}
```

Comment: This version suits very well if you don't have access to C++11 tuples. +1

Answer (score 1):

You could pass by reference instead of returning a value for example:

```
void getValues(int & yrs, int & lbs, string & clr) const
{
   yrs = this->age;
   lbs = this->weight;
   clr = this->color;
}
```

Comment: Breaks const correctness and makes chaining function calls impossible.

Comment: Fixed the const but can't do anything with chaining.

Comment: That's not what I meant. I was referring to the fact that you have to make your three objects non-const. You cannot create an `int const years;` and then initialize it with `getValues`.

Comment: Thanks. I see.. I have never thought of that mainly because l would not do it this way in practice.

Answer (score 0):

You could write a function that gets references as input like so:

```
void getAllTheValues(int& age, int& weight, std::string& color) {
  age = this->age;
  weight = this->weight;
  color = this->color;
}
```

and use it like that

```
int age, weight;
string color;

myClass object();
object.getAllTheValues(age, weight, color);
```